# Открытие изображение стандартными средствами на C#

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь открыть изображение через код на C#, но в таком случае нет возможность листать все изображения в папке с исходным изображением

Вот часть моего кода:
Process.Start(pathImage)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код Вашего приложения. И прочтите, пожалуйста, [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `Process.Start` запустит приложение, ассоциированное с данным типом файлов. У разных пользователей будут разные приложения: у одного IrfanView, у другого - XnView, у третьего вообще Photoshop. И каждое из них по своему может отреагировать на переданный в него путь.

Comment: У меня не получилось заставить Photos работать так, как вам надо.

Answer (score 0):

Метод Process.Start передает управление операционной системе, предоставляя ей решать каким образом поступить с файлом. Вы не можете напрямую управлять результатом.

Если вам необходимо реализовать перелистывание изображений, реализуйте это в своей программе самостоятельно, используя компонент [PictureBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox) для отображения изображений.

Для получения списка файлов и навигации по файловой системе используйте следующие классы:

- [System.IO.FileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo)
- [System.IO.DirectoryInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo)
- [System.IO.Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory)
- [System.IO.File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file)

Для загрузки изображения в память используйте метод [PictureBox.Load](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.load).

Ищите примеры здесь:

- [How to get information about files, folders, and drives (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-get-information-about-files-folders-and-drives)
- [How do I list all images in a folder using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918478)
- [How do I change a PictureBox's image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487901)

Comment: Мне необходимо именно стандартными средствами открывать изображение